# ¿Como realizar una acción por un atributo data en jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, html5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<span class="ejemple" data-id="10">Ejemplo 1</span>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="20">Ejemplo 2</span>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="30">Ejemplo 3</span>
```

En este caso quisiera hacer algo como esto:

```
$("ejemplo[data-id='10']").click(function(e) {
   /* Aquí va el código a ejecutar*/
});
```

El punto es seleccionar el span mediante la clase que tenga el atributo data con valor 10.

Answer (score 3):

Las otras respuestas funcionan, pero NO son la mejor forma de abordar los atributos data en jQuery, es más fácil aún:

Existe el método [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) que maneja directamente los attributos que inicien con `data-`, con este método puedes tanto obtener los valores de un elemento del DOM como asignárselos.

```
$(".ejemple").click(function(e) {

    /* lo que quieras hacer con $(this).data("id") */
    console.log($(this).data("id"));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Es probable que necesites jugar con los atributos `data-`aqui tienes un ejemplo de cómo podría ser:

```js
    $(".ejemple").click(function(e) {
        var myID = $(this).attr("data-id");
        console.log(myID);
        if(myID === "10")
        {
            console.log('has presionado el id 10');
            /* Aquí va el código a ejecutar*/          
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="10">Ejemplo 1</span>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="20">Ejemplo 2</span>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="30">Ejemplo 3</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué hay de malo en como lo tienes?

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]'), function(e) {
 e.onclick = function() {
    const id = Number(this.dataset.id);
    let rgb = null;
    // hacer algo con el id
    switch(id) {
     case 10: rgb = '#3498db'; break;
      case 20: rgb = "#e74c3c"; break;
      case 30: rgb = "#1abc9c"; break;
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb;
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.88);
}
[data-id] {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  padding: .1rem .45rem;
}
[data-id]:first-of-type {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
[data-id]:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
[data-id]:last-of-type {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<h1>Elije un color</h1>
<span data-id="10">R</span>
<span data-id="20">G</span>
<span data-id="30">B</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ibas bien, solo debes cambiar el query selección, por le siguiente: `$("span[data-id='10']")`, mira acá te dejo el snippet.

```js
$("span[data-id='10']").click(function(e) {
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="10">Ejemplo 1</span>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="20">Ejemplo 2</span>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="30">Ejemplo 3</span>
```

---

**Actualización por alternativa**

Ahora, si bien lo que buscas es asignar el evento a todos los `span`, sin importar el `data-id`, entonces puedes hacerlo con el siguiente código:

```js
$("span.ejemple").click(function(e){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="10">Ejemplo 1</span>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="20">Ejemplo 2</span>
<span class="ejemple" data-id="30">Ejemplo 3</span>
```